# Custom events not working in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, events, custom-events

I have an event called SelectEvent. Whenever I click the buyer, the select event should be launched. But that is not what is happening.

My code of base:

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class FashionFrenzy extends MovieClip
    {

        public var Buyer_mc:Buyer;
        public var Buyers:Array;
        private var BuyerNumber:Number;
        public var xpositions:Array;
        public var ypositions:Array;
        public var SelectedBuyer:Number;

        public function FashionFrenzy()
        {

            GameTimeController();

            xpositions=new Array();
            xpositions.push(523,563,603);

            ypositions=new Array();
            ypositions.push(377,377,377);

            Buyers = new Array  ;
            BuyerNumber=0;


            Time_mc.gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,GenerateBuyers);
            addEventListener(SelectEvent.BUYERSELECT,showselectbuyer);


        }


        public function GameTimeController()
        {
            Time_mc.StartGame();

        }
        public function showselectbuyer(event:SelectEvent):void
        {
            trace("Bamba");         
        }
        public function GenerateBuyers(event:TimerEvent):void
        {
            if(BuyerNumber<6)
            {
                if (Math.random() < 0.01)
                {
                    var position:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
                    var newBuyer_mc = new Buyer(xpositions[position],ypositions[position],BuyerNumber);
                    ypositions[position]-=40;
                    Buyers.push(newBuyer_mc);
                    addChild(newBuyer_mc);

                    BuyerNumber++;

                }
            }

                for each (var buyer_mc:Buyer in Buyers)
                {
                    if(buyer_mc.walking==true)
                    {

                        buyer_mc.Enter();


                    }


                }


        }








    }

}
```

My code of the buyer:

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Buyer extends MovieClip
    {
        public var buyerTimer:Timer;
        public var walking:Boolean;
        public var stopposition:Number;
        public var buyerCode:Number;



        public function Buyer(startx:Number, stopy:Number, code:Number)
        {
            x=startx;
            stopposition=stopy;
            walking=true;
            buyerCode=code;

            BuyerProperties();

        }
        public function Enter():void
        {

            if(y>stopposition)
            {

                walking=false;
                StartFunction();

            }
            else
            {
                y= y+3;
            }
        }
        public function BuyerProperties():void
        {
            buyerTimer = new Timer( 25 );
            trace(" I am generated");

        }
        public function StartFunction():void
        {

            buyerTimer.start();
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,Select);

            trace("My timer starts now within Buyer.as");
        }
        public function Select(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace(buyerCode);
            dispatchEvent( new SelectEvent(SelectEvent.BUYERSELECT));
        }




    }

}
```

Now that when I'm clicking the buyer, the MouseEvent.CLICK is activated and then in the buyer.as, buyercode is traced on the screen. But the event is not dispatched or else it is dispatched but the eventlistener is not executing the code. I'm not getting any runtime errors. the function "showselectbuyer" is never even launched.

How should I solve it?

Comment: While reviewing your code, noticed that `Buyers = new Array  ;` should be `Buyers = new Array();`.

Comment: Okay I'm fixing that. Thank you. But fixing that isn't making a differene in the problem I'm facing.

Comment: Are you bubbling your events for the `SelectEvent` class?

Comment: FYI I recommend using AS3 Signals rather than Events. https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals

Comment: what does bubbling mean? @SlyRaskal

Comment: I will surely check out about signals. :) @Allan

Comment: parentheses can be omitted for constructors that don't require parameters. That is the case for Array so "new Array" is correct but "[]" is faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is incorrect. The provided solution works but for the wrong reasons. It creates a direct dependency to the object supposed to listen to the custom event and then makes that object be the dispatcher. All together this makes the whole idea of using event/custom event unnecessary at best since in that case a simple callback would work just as well. Instead using the useCapture flag would make the whole system work as expected:

```
addEventListener(SelectEvent.BUYERSELECT,showselectbuyer, true);
```

The accepted solution is also the inverse way of dealing with non DisplayObject event propagation. The dispatcher should be the listener (no dependencies) and not the listener should be the dispatcher (dependency necessary).

Comment: "That parameter changes the phase of the listening. It does not make the Event bubble" where in my answer does it says it makes the event bubble?  Bubbling or not if you don't useCapture to true you won't catch the bubbling phase of an event.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. This still seems somewhat off-topic and confusing. Knowing how to capture in the bubbling phase is not helpful without knowing how to make the Event bubble in the first place, because that's a property of the Event object itself. And no, setCapture is not required to listen for a bubbling Event.

Comment: if you run the PO code with simply setting useCapture to true, the event will be caught which I think would be a much better answer to the PO's question than the one accepted. That was the purpose of the answer I posted. The accepted answer incorrectly creates a direct dependency that completely defeats the purpose of using custom event but still uses custom events. I believe something had to be said.

Comment: Could you please edit that into your answer? As it stands now, it could be misunderstood that passing true as the 3rd parameter to addEventListener would catch an Event in the bubbling phase "no matter if custom or not". But there is no bubbling phase for an Event that doesn't bubble and this custom event does not bubble. The parameter value true causes the capture phase to be used, which makes this work. It's good that your answer solves the problem, but explaining it with bubbling feels somewhat incorrect and is probably confusing to the OP.

Comment: I tried modifying the code as you asked me to @BotMaster and it worked again. I think I understood what you meant but I'm still confused what exactly bubbling or useCapture do. It would be much help if I would get a clearer idea on what those are.

Answer (score -1):

The trouble with custom events is that they don't bubble up the display list, so in case your event to be registered you need to dispatch it to the class instance that has a listener to that event attached. In your case it's an instance of `FashionFrenzy`. Apparently buyers don't know about a fashion frenzy instance they are running in, so they dispatch the event to themselves and wonder why no one else listens. In order to resolve this, either attach the listener to the buyer, or in the buyer class dispatch the event to `parent`, which is apparently the instance you want to receive the event.

Comment: Thank you a lot. adding "parent" worked perfectly fine.

Comment: @Mana adding the listener to the buyer object is the better option. With your current setup, only the parent of a buyer can listen for the Event. This defeats the point of using Events in the first place, which is creating a loose coupling between two objects. That's the case if any object can add a listener to a buyer. But the way you do it now, your structure is very strict. **Only** the parent will dispatch the events.

Comment: The correct solution is to simply set useCapture to true. Using "parent" even though it does provide a solution to the PO problem is defeating completely the purpose of using event in the first place and is incorrectly tagged as the correct answer.

Comment: I understood what you want to say @null and I'm still trying to figure out how is BotMaster 's method correct, though it helped me out and I have a better idea.